# Prove the statement 'World is not flat'

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, graph-theory

In my graph theory book exercise, I found a problem that:

> Prove that **the World is not flat** using Mathematics

[image]

This picture is used in the exercise, but no idea of applying it.

I would have used the angles don't add to $180^\circ$, but the author is using a fourth city.

Comment: Do they mean something like 'cover it with hexagons and twelve pentagons'?

Comment: @Michael There are hint in the exercise as 'Use planar graph concept',but I can't figured it out

Comment: Wow, you seriously didn't think that figure was relevant? Please post all relevant information from the beginning. Thank you.

Comment: Can you find complete graph on 5 vertices i.e. $K_5$ inside the map of the world?

Comment: I think that adding the information about the book where this comes from would be useful. Is it Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell by Zee, [page 66](https://books.google.com/books?id=5Dy1hlKvmCYC&pg=PA66)? (If it is, this seems to be closer to differential geometry than to graph theory.)

Comment: @Hailey You have repeatedly asked why your question was put on hold - for example, in your [most recent edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1816766/4). I am not sure whether it is the same question, but I have tried to post [what I think you are asking](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818104/given-distances-between-four-cities-how-to-show-that-they-cannot-be-in-the-same) and include sufficient context there.

Comment: BTW at least giving the title and author of the "graph theory book" where you found this would be, in my opinion, a good way of adding context to your question. ("In my graph theory book" sound much more vague than if you provide exact bibliographic information identifying the book.)

Comment: Hint: Since you don't have angles at your disposal, you have to replace them by distances via the cosine rule. Assume that the world is flat and that you know the mutual distances between Berlin, Barcelona and Paris. The you can compute the distance from Rome to Paris from its distance to Berlin and Barcelona. If this does not agree with the real distance then the assumption that the world is flat was wrong.

Comment: @Hailey Even if you do not wish to add some more context to your question, could you at least say whether you consider it to be the same question as [the one I posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818104/given-distances-shortest-paths-between-four-cities-how-to-show-that-they-cann)? So that one of them can be closed as a duplicate or perhaps they could be merged.

Comment: You wrote that the hint given there was: "Use planar graph concept." That seems strange to me for two reasons: [$K_4$ is planar](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22K_4%22+planar&tbm=isch). And even graph which is not planar can be drawn in a plane. But only in a such way that edges will intersect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two diagonals $p$ and $q$ of a plane quadrilateral and the four side lengths $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are related by the Cayley-Menger determinant: $$\det\pmatrix{0&a^2&p^2&d^2&1\cr a^2&0&b^2&q^2&1\cr p^2&b^2&0&c^2&1\cr d^2&q^2&c^2&0&1\cr1&1&1&1&0\cr}=0$$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Properties_of_the_diagonals_in_some_quadrilaterals

Comment: Now all you need are the distances, which you can get from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+from+Paris+to+Berlin)