# Proof of the statement 'World is not flat' by graph theory

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

In my graph theory book exercise,I found a problem that:

Prove that,**World is not flat** using Mathematics

[image]

This picture is used in the exercise,but no idea of applying it.

Comment: Did they provide you with the lengths of the lines?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816766

Comment: What do you know about the Pythagorean theorem on a Euclidean plane?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really directly related to "graph theory".

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET I think there is probably a graph theory proof related to the fact that K5 is not planar, but I'm not sure how exactly to do it.

Comment: @Ian For what it's worth K5 cannot be embedded into the sphere either. (There's a cute, short proof of this using the Euler characteristic that's a nice exercise, too.)

Comment: On-topic: you can take three (not *any* three) of the distances to find a triangle. Given any of the other three, if the whole thing were planar, you'd be confining the fourth point to a circle. Given a fifth distance as well, you'd be confining the fourth point to be one of at most two points. Adding a sixth distance will thus typically be impossible (because there are only at most two admissible values of this sixth distance). I think this "two" corresponds to the possibility of the resulting quadrilateral being concave vs. convex.

Comment: Take a small region of the earth which is "locally 2-dimensional" and take four places in it that "nearly" provide the four vertices of a rectangle. For instance, take the four corners on the field of a soccer stadium. Then one clearly can connect these four places by streets/lines that do not intersect each other ($K_4$ is planar). Also, clearly, if we take a point at the opposite side of the earth, and connect it with the other four points in the shortest possible way (through the inner of the earth), then these lines will also not intersect each other or any of the previous lines.

Comment: So my idea for using graph theory would be: The earth cannot be planar, because $K_5$ is not planar. This is not quite related to the figure, but I do not see how 4 points and their distances on the earth should suffice to show that the earth is not planar using graph theory (i.e. letting them define a graph), since $K_4$ can be drawn on a plane.

Comment: @Watson Right observation : In fact **Hailey has already asked this question 7 hours ago**, and this question has been put "on hold". Please Hailey dont' do that, it is not a correct behavior.

Comment: But doesn't my question a valid one ?I put it again as my previous question was put on Hold

Comment: One of my question should be valid,both are either on hold or duplicate,now how can get the answer.

Comment: Since you asked what to do to get an answer - if you read the on-hold banner in your other question, it gives an explanation. "This question is missing context or other details: Please [improve the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) by providing additional context..." If you click on the text "improve the question", this links brings you to the post (on meta) explaining how good questions should look and what are good ways to add missing context.